# What is a good image size for full page background

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a picture, that want to use as full background image in html. I follow the tutorials on https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ page but on my site does not look nice at all. My background picture has a size from 1200 x 1200.

My questions are:

- What is a good picture size for full background page?
- Which format should I use jpeg or svg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend svg because it scales up without loss of quality. When using svg the actual size does not matter, because it is a vector image. However it is important to have the same aspect ratio as the screen you are targeting to, most often 16:9.

Answer (score 1):

The most screens are 1920x1080, 1024x768.
Maybe you should use media queries?

Check this out: [But please note, these statics are for w3schools visitors](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp)

Answer (score 1):

The method described on css-tricks makes a background that will be resizable to the screen resolution. You'll notice that if you shrink your browser window that the image will get smaller and look 'nicer'.

So, you'll need to find an image with a resolution that supports at least 1080p (1920x1080). Just imagine someone viewing your website on their device at full screen. Some people do have screen that are larger than this, so try your best to support up to 1920x1440, even though 4k screens are becoming popular now.